# How does partitioning in MapReduce exactly work?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I think I have a fair understanding of the MapReduce programming model in general, but even after reading the original paper and some other sources many details are unclear to me, especially regarding the partitioning of the intermediate results.

I will quickly summarize my understanding of MapReduce so far: We have a potentially very large input data set, which is automatically split up into M different pieces by the MR-Framework. For each piece, the framework schedules one map task which is executed by one of the available processors/machines in my cluster. Each of the M map tasks outputs a set of Key-Value-Pairs, which is stored locally on the same machine that executed this map task. Each machine divides its disk into R partitions and distributes its computed intermediate key value pairs based on the intermediate keys among the partitions. Then, the framework starts for each distinct intermediate key one reduce task which is again executed by any of the available machines.

Now my questions are:

1. In some tutorials it sounds like there could be map and reduce tasks executed in parallel. Is this right? How could that be, assuming that for each distinct intermediate key only one reduce task is started? Do we not have to wait until the last map task is finished before we can start the first reduce task?
2. As we have one reduce task per distinct intermediate key, is it right that each reduce task requires the executing machine to load the corresponding partition from every other machine? Potentially, every machine can have a key-value-pair with the desired intermediate key, so for each reduce task we potentially have to query all other machines. Is that really efficient?
3. The original paper says that the number of partitions (R) is specified by the user. But isn’t a partition the input for a reduce task? Or more exactly: Isn’t the union of all partitions with the same number among all machines the input of one reduce task? That would mean, that R depends on the number of distinct intermediate keys which the user usually doesn’t know.

Conceptually it is clear what the input and outputs of the map and reduce functions/tasks are. But I think I haven’t yet understood MapReduce on the technical level. Could somebody please help me understanding?

Comment: I think we have one `map task` for every machine and have M `map function`. Every `map task` can have multiple `map function`. After one `map function` finished its work, another `map function` will be assigned to it.

Comment: It is not true Seyed, we can have more than on maptask per machine which is governed by number of map slots configuration in a datanode.If we donot specify this, the number of map tasks will be equal to number of processor cores!

Answer (score 12):

1. You can start the reducer tasks while the map tasks are still running (using a feature known as slowstart), but the reducers can only run the copy phase (acquiring the completed results from the completed map tasks. It will need to wait for all the mappers to complete before it can actually perform the final sort and reduce.
2. A reduce task actually processes zero, one or more keys (rather than a discrete tasks for each key). Each reducer will need to acquire the map output from each map task that relates to its partition before these intermediate outputs are sorted and then reduced one key set at a time.
3. Back to the note in 2 - a reducer task (one for each partition) runs on zero, one or more keys rather than a single task for each discrete key.

It's also important to understand the spread and variation of your intermediate key as it is hashed and modulo'd (if using the default HashPartitioner) to determine which reduce partition should process that key. Say you had an even number of reducer tasks (10), and output keys that always hashed to an even number - then in this case the modulo of these hashs numbers and 10 will always be an even number, meaning that the odd numbered reducers would never process any data.

Comment: That already helps me a lot. My problem was that I thought a reduce task was the same as a single call of the reduce function. Now it makes more sense. But I am still confused with question no. 2. You confirmed that a machine must possibly query all other machines to execute a reduce task. That means that we need n^2 inter-machine data transfers in the reduce phase. I thought that scalability is the major advantage of MapReduce. But quadratically growing data transfers don't sound like scalability...?

Answer (score 8):

Addendum to what Chris said,

Basically, a partitioner class in Hadoop (e.g. Default [HashPartitioner](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/partition/HashPartitioner.html))

has to implement this function,

```
int getPartition(K key, V value, int numReduceTasks)
```

This function is responsible for returning you the partition number and you get the number of reducers you fixed when starting the job from the **numReduceTasks** variable, as seen for in the HashPartitioner.

Based on what integer the above function return, Hadoop selects node where the reduce task for a particular key should run.

Hope this helps.